# Best way to persist lot of data into an object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a project where I have to parse files (probably really large files) and save each string in another entity. The bundle is going to deal with a lot filetypes(CSV,XML,JSON,etc). I'm going to create a parser for each one of these types, that returns an array of strings

```
  $em2 = $this->getDoctrine()
      ->getEntityManager();

  foreach ($Parser as $key => $value) {  

      $str_or[] = new StringOrigin();
      $str_or[$key]->setSTORString($value);
      /..
      $em2->persist($str_or[$key]);
   }

 $em2->flush();
```

$Paser here is the array of strings parsed from the file. StringOrigin is the entity. How much data could handle the entity manager? Am I doing this the right way? If not, would [bach processing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html)
handle this better? Also, is there a way I can do only one INSERT without using going through DQL?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine's entity manager is not really designed for massive number of objects.  In my experience, thousands of records are fine but you start to hit limits as you move into 10s of thousands.  Of course it depends on the complexity of your entities.

Take a look at Doctrine's Database Access Layer (DBAL).  Basically:

```
$connection = $entityManager->getConnection();
```

Gives you a thinly wrapped PDO object which talks directly to the database.  Prepare an INSERT statement then keep calling it with different parameters.  Doing so let me handle 10s of thousands of records in one request.  Have not had to go further than that.

And consider testing your parsers without doing any database interactions.  It's easy to hit PHP's memory limits if you are not careful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to do more tests with my parser. Wouldn't be bad to use Prepared SQL statements ?